# Exit with error message in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, isset, exit-code

I am checking if a particular value is set using isset. I want to quit the HTML with displaying error message like "name not found , Enter a valid name". Currently I am checking like

```
if ((! isset($_GET["name"])) or (! is_dir($_GET["name"])) or (empty($_GET["name"]))) {

    Print "Name not found, Enter a valid name"
}
```

After the print, I want to exit without further execution of HTML code. how can I exit with the my error message and no default error message from PHP

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Die or exit: see the php documentation

http://php.net/die

http://php.net/exit

```
die ("I'm dyin over here");
```

Comment: please see my comments below and if you could provide solution, it will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 die("Name not found, Enter a valid name");
```

That should help!

Regards,
Felix

Comment: But this did not display the text in browser. when I looked as page source, I could see the message. how can I have it display in the broswer where the URL is run

Comment: @user1988876 this piece of code is supposed to show __Name not found, Enter a valid name__ in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) or [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) methods. This will halt all PHP and HTML from being displayed or executed.

Example:

```
if ((! isset($_GET["name"])) or (! is_dir($_GET["name"])) or (empty($_GET["name"]))) {

    die("Name not found, Enter a valid name");
}
```